# Create a trigger to update another table in Netezza SQL

Tags: sql, triggers, netezza

I'm trying to create a trigger in Netezza SQL so when there is a new row added in aTable, the same new row will be automatically added into bTable.

The columns in aTable and bTable are not equivalent. So I want aTable.Column1 inserts into bTable.Column3, aTable.Column2 into bTable.Column6, aTable.Column3 into bTable.Column9, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid that netezza does not support triggers.

What is the business problem you are trying to solve?
Most likely we can help you with a different approach?

Comment: Hi Lars, I have two tables, say aTable will be inserted 1 or more new rows by bot every day, and I hope to insert those new data into bTable once the aTable got updated. The update in bTable can be set at 4pm everyday. One more thing is as I mentioned, the column names are different between two tables, I only need 4 columns data in aTable updated into 4 columns in bTable.